# GATTService interface doesn't appear

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus, bluez, gatt

My goal is to activate a notification on a Bluetooth Low Energy device to receive data using the DBus Interface so I downloaded the last Bluez version (5.33).

I read the README file and I used the `--enable-experimental` options
during the configuration.

Now I can only scan for the LE device and connect with it using the `Adpeter1` and `Device1` interfaces. In the next step I need to connect to the `GATTService` interface on the device but using d-feet I can't see this interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start `bluetoothd` with the -E (experimental) option.